# Retrofit get bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, retrofit

I tried to use Retrofit library to get from server bitmap in this way:

```
@GET("/products/{ean}/image")
Bitmap getBitmapByEan(@Path("ean") String ean);
```

But I recived an error:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected   BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

I probably can't get Bitmap in this way because as I see it is string type not a bitmap and I cannot convert it. Am I right and maybe is it possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO !  please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Square's Retrofit currently Supports GSON and XML Content Formats types like this

**GSON:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
    .create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

**XML:**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.soundcloud.com")
    .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
    .build();

SoundCloudService service = restAdapter.create(SoundCloudService.class);
```

You are dealing with the File I/O type, either you need to you need to build your own SimpleBitmapConverter()  or simply use other Image loading libs like [**Koush ION**](https://github.com/koush/ion#load-an-image-into-an-imageview)

**Load an image into an ImageView/Bitmaps with Koush ION:**

// This is the "long" way to do build an ImageView request... it allows you to set headers, etc.

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/image.png")
.withBitmap()
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.intoImageView(imageView);

// but for brevity, use the ImageView specific builder...
Ion.with(imageView)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.load("http://example.com/image.png");
```